# How to get correct intercept of a lm with log variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

Here is some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame('x' = c(230890.00, 71023.25, 296.00, 217530.00, 736550.00, 285529.50, 15210.25, 20317.00, 25157.75,
                     1272.50, 7817.75, 61297.50, 9085.00, 16047.25, 10008.75, 2438.75),
                 'y' = c(2.030330e-11, 1.016549e-05, 9.308836e-17, 5.587085e-02, 1.122631e+01, 1.104037e-06, 1.609258e-04,
                     1.653132e-04, 1.849783e-04, 6.611519e-15, 6.096827e-14, 1.197042e-09, 7.425932e-08, 2.398086e-05,
                     5.677278e-13, 2.704369e-15))
```

I want to plot this data as a scatter plot, on log axis with a line showing the linear regression and a label showing the regression equation and R^2 value.

To do this I have the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = F, col = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed') +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = df$y ~ df$x, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = '*plain(\',\')~')), 
               parse = T ) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10',
                 breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
                 labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10',
                 breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
                 labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 11),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black'),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'black'),
    legend.position = 'none'
  )
```

Which gives me this output:

[image]

However, as you can see the intercept is wrong. I am assuming that this is because I have not log transformed x and y in the formula of `stat_poly_eq`, but if I do log transform them then they won't be on the same scale as the graph axis (the intercept becomes -26).

How can I get the formula to show the intercept is at around 10^-16?